# What is the request that whatsapp cloud api does to verify a webhook?

Tags: https, webhooks, whatsapp

I'm able to verify the webhook using glitch from the getting started:

https://glitch.com/edit/?fbclid=IwAR2YTjZuGGM9Hi6T_v1eZh_nV6_HY3RYn_8lll4gY1REa_bJy6ZAuq6tkKQ#!/whatsapp-cloud-api-echo-bot

my local server (in a subdomain with https enabled) has the same behavior as glitch and show "WEBHOOK_VERIFIED" on the log for the request:

```
/webhook?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.verify_token=xpto123&hub.challenge=123
```

but when try to verify my local server the request from meta does not reach the server.

[image: chrome showing that the connection to the server is secured]

Comment: I decided to forget the local server, and run it on a digital ocean droplet, the same code with and it worked. I'm believe that maybe meta knows that it's a customer ip address and simply does not send the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more tests I found that my local server was been blocked by the ISP, understood it after test with another connection.

Comment: So what did you do and were you finally able to register your webhook using localhost?

Comment: I followed the instructions in these link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks/
I'm believe that if my ISP don't blocks https to my local server everything should works from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I made my own server and had tried ngrok and other programs to run it from local host with https redirect but whatsapp doesn't allow the use of those programs.

In the end, my error was that the URL HAS to end in `/webhook` or else, it won't even send the request. Then it'll send a GET request and you have to return the `hub.challenge` query param after making sure that the provided token from them is the one you set up. This is my code using NodeJS

`if(req.query['hub.verify_token'] === process.env.VERIFY_TOKEN) return res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge'])`